# Covert RAW Lytro images (.lfp) to TIFF.

Tags: lytro

I recently started using images from the Lytro Illum. I am more interested in playing with the Light Field image as how the sensor captures it (like the 100,000 small hexagons). The lfpspillter http://lightfield-forum.com/2012/07/lytro-hack-how-to-extract-data-and-jpg-files-from-the-lfp-file-format-using-lfpsplitter/ works pretty good and I am able to save the jpegs and the raw file. But, the issue is when I am trying to convert the raw file to tiff. I did try using raw2tiff http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/ and few other tools as well. Unfortunately, I am not successful as I get only noise and not a proper grayscale image. I understand Lytro has made many updates over time and this might be the problem, but I would really like to know if there is a solution to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The open-source tool [plenopticam](https://github.com/hahnec/plenopticam/) is capable of extracting Lytro's raw images as a tiff file apart from other rendering functionalities. It is a standalone cross-platform application that only requires Python which comes with the executables found at:

- https://github.com/hahnec/plenopticam/releases/

It might be a bit late for your question, but helpful for anyone else encountering your problem. I should mention that I am the author of this software.